# Move a control in a circle at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, picturebox

I know you can change a control's x/y location at runtime and I can use a timer to move it up/down/left/right/diagonally but how can you programatically move it in a circle?

For example, if I had a PictureBox control at the 12 o'clock position on my main form, can I move that picture box in a circle, finishing at its start position, on a button click?

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on how I would do that?

Comment: If you can move a control vertically and horizontally, you can also move it in a circle :)

Comment: Yes I know that, it's the logic of it that's the hard part. That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a small class deriving from `PictureBox` which should let you achieve your result easily enough. Everytime you call `RotateStep` its location will change accordingly. Angle and speed are expressed in radians, distance in pixels.

```
class RotatingPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }

    public void RotateStep()
    {
        var oldX = Math.Cos(Angle)*Distance;
        var oldY = Math.Sin(Angle)*Distance;
        Angle += Speed;
        var x = Math.Cos(Angle)*Distance - oldX;
        var y = Math.Sin(Angle)*Distance - oldY;
        Location += new Size((int) x, (int) y);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var pictureBox = new RotatingPictureBox
    {
        Angle = Math.PI,
        Speed = Math.PI/20,
        Distance = 50,
        BackColor = Color.Black,
        Width = 10,
        Height = 10,
        Location = new Point(100, 50)
    };
    Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    var timer = new Timer {Interval = 10};
    timer.Tick += (sender, args) => pictureBox.RotateStep();
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Do you know which direction I should head in to have a group of controls move along the same path?

Comment: @user1679851 Derive from `UserControl` instead of `PictureBox`. Technically, you could also derive from `Panel` or another container.

Comment: So apply the same RotateStep function for each control in the container? Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 4):

Use sinus and cosinus functions.

Look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499952/290343) for example.

A concrete C# example exists [here](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/Draw_Circle_Pixel.html).
In case that the link will not exist some day, here is the source code for drawing 25 increasing radius circles on a form:

```
void PutPixel(Graphics g, int x, int y, Color c)
{
      Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1, 1);
      bm.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Red);
      g.DrawImageUnscaled(bm, x, y);
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{  
      Graphics myGraphics = e.Graphics;

      myGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
      double radius = 5;
      for (int j = 1; j <= 25; j++)
      {
            radius = (j + 1) * 5;
            for (double i = 0.0; i < 360.0; i += 0.1)
            {
                double angle = i * System.Math.PI / 180;
                int x = (int)(150 + radius * System.Math.Cos(angle));
                int y = (int)(150 + radius * System.Math.Sin(angle));

                PutPixel(myGraphics, x, y, Color.Red);
            }
      }
      myGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]